# Modify the saturation of image

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios8

How can I modify the saturation of a UIImage?

I want to turn it to greyscale gradually and also by animation.
I am writing my application with Swift and IOS8.

Comment: Do some research try to implement something and post a specific question about a particular technical challenge. You can't expect people to answer you 'how do i do this' questions.  Heres a pointer : https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000136-SW42

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok with implementing a lib, take a look at GPUImage, which provides dozens of highly optimized image filters: https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage